# G(n) is the number of n x n matrices J with real entries that satisfy J^2 + In = 0. Show that G(n)=0 iff n is odd.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Since *In* is the identity matrix of order n, visualizing $J^2=-In$, how can I show that *J* can be a real matrix only when *n* is even?

Comment: Introducing the number sounds weird - of course, whenever there is such a $J$, there are continuum-many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|J|^2 = |-I_n| = (-1)^n$

If n is odd, then $|J|^2 = -1$, not possible for a real matrix.

---

btw, to make the proof complete, you still need to prove that when n is even, you can always construct at least one such $J$.

For n=2, one example would be 
$$
\left[
\begin{aligned}
    0 && 1 \\
    -1 && 0 
\end{aligned}\right]
$$

but you still need to find a general form for all odd n.